# Laravel error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" when trying to update row

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to do something very simple: When a user clicks a button, a column for a corresponding row is changed from 0 to 1.

The button goes to:

```
href="/redeem-coupon/{{ $coupon->coupon_code }}"
```

That route is set up as follows:

```
Route::post('/redeem-coupon/{coupon_code}', 'CouponController@redeemCoupon');
```

And the controller is:

```
  public function redeemCoupon ($coupon_code)

    {
        $coupon = \DB::table('coupons')->where('coupon_code', $coupon_code)->first();
        $coupon->redeemed = 1;
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

I have some existing code that uses a route to display some info from a row when the rows 'coupon_code' is working so everything else is working fine except for this part. Clicking the button gives
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException "

Answer (score 2):

You are doing GET request while route is set for POST. Either change your route

```
Route::get(....
```

or switch to use HTML  form and POST submission.

Comment: I tried HTML form and POSt but that results in nothing being updated on the row. I tried adding in "$coupon->save();" but that gives the error "Call to undefined method stdClass::save()"

Comment: And I tried "$coupon->update();" but that results in "Call to undefined method stdClass::update()"

Answer (score 2):

Change your route to intercept the get request instead of post:

```
Route::get('/redeem-coupon/{coupon_code}', 'CouponController@redeemCoupon');
```

**EDIT:**

The error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means that you are trying to access a non existing route, but sometimes you will get this error even if the route is setting correctly, in this case make sure that your route is above all other routes pointing to the same controller because some other routes may intercept your query.

Comment: If you put your route on top of  web.php are you getting the same error ?